# How to connect different networks based on vlans using layer 3 switches and router?

Tags: cisco, routing, layer3, packet-tracer, eigrp

[image: diagram]

This is a simplified version of my network diagram. How do I make both network speak to each other?

I'm confused because earlier I used routers and switches, and I connected them using OSPF or EIGRP. Now, I've tried to set up EIGRP on the layer 3 switch and then on the router but I still can't ping from one network to another. I just can't understand the concept of layer 3 switches in conjunction with vlans.

These are my switches' configurations:

**Switch 1:**

```
int fa0/1
 switchport access vlan 35
!
int fa0/2
 switchport access vlan 40
!
int fa0/3
 switchport access vlan 45
!
int fa0/4
 switchport access vlan 50
!
int gig0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q 
 switchport mode trunk
!
```

**Switch 2:**

```
int fa0/1
 switchport access vlan 45
!
int fa0/2
 switchport access vlan 55
!
int fa0/3
 switchport access vlan 40
!
int fa0/4
 switchport access vlan 60
!
int gig0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
int vlan 35
 ip address 10.100.50.17 255.255.255.240
!
int vlan 40
 ip address 10.100.50.33 255.255.255.240
!
int vlan 45
 ip address 10.100.50.49 255.255.255.240
!
int vlan 50
 ip address 10.100.50.65 255.255.255.240
!
int vlan 55
 ip address 10.100.50.81 255.255.255.240
!
int vlan 60
 ip address 10.100.50.97 255.255.255.240
!
exit
!
ip dhcp pool vlan35
network 10.100.50.16 255.255.255.240
default-router 10.100.50.17
!
ip dhcp pool vlan40
network 10.100.50.32 255.255.255.240
default-router 10.100.50.33
!
ip dhcp pool vlan45
network 10.100.50.48 255.255.255.240
default-router 10.100.50.49
!
ip dhcp pool vlan50
network 10.100.50.64 255.255.255.240
default-router 10.100.50.65
!
ip dhcp pool vlan55
network 10.100.50.80 255.255.255.240
default-router 10.100.50.81
!
ip dhcp pool vlan60
network 10.100.50.96 255.255.255.240
default-router 10.100.50.97
!
exit
!
end
!
```

The same thing is configured on another network which has 192.168.85.xx network address. I can ping from one VLAN to another inside one network but I can't do it between two networks.

I also wonder if I have to write the ip routing command  on interface of the switch which is directly connected with the router.

Comment: `I've tried to set up EIGRP on the layer 3 switch and then on the router` => please include the EIGRP config of the switches and the complete config of the router. Also, from where to where are you testing the ping?

Comment: http://www.beetxt.com/aoR/
Initially I didn't configure EIGRP on router but after it didn't work I configured everything on everything and it still doesn't work. It even is not allowing me to ping from vlans to the router interface (18.0.0.2)

Comment: There's a lot of stuff to be fixed there, don't have time right now to list it all (will try tomorrow if nobody else does), but I think your eigrp might actually be working  (did you check neighbors and routing table?) and the ACL on the router may be simply dropping the traffic?

Comment: I completely deleted the ACL on the router and I'm able to ping the router, both interfaces, but I can't reach the other network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you enable routing on a layer-3 switch, it is only doing layer-2 switching, not anything with layer-3.

How do you suppose that the networks on one side know where to send traffic destined for the networks on the other side? Routers, including layer-3 switches, need to know where to send traffic, otherwise the traffic gets dropped. Routers get routers three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Dynamically learned routes from routing protocols

You either need to manually configure routes, or you need to run a routing protocols between the layer-3 devices.

The real way to do it is to configure IP routing on all the layer-3 switches, and configure the links between the layer-3 switches and the router to be routed links, not trunks. Then you run a common routing protocol on all the layer-3 devices.

Comment: http://www.beetxt.com/aoR/  
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Each VLAN is a network, Basically according to your diagram you have 9 networks, with a Router you don't need to do routing with a layer-3 switch, However maybe you don't have 9 ports on your router for your 9 networks, in this situation, you can use a technique called router on a stick by creating virtual port for each vlan, here is an example.

on the router

Interface Fa0/1
ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.240
interface Fa0/1.2
encapsulation dot1q 2
ip address 192.168.1.65 255.255.255.192
interface Fa0/1.10
encapsulation dot1q 10
ip address 192.168.1.129 255.255.255.224